# Maturity date with PHP

Tags: php, date

**Edit :**

### Maturity date, what is it ?

I'm not native english speaker. Sorry about that. I think the best we can do, is to define Maturity Date.

> A maturity date is a date that indicates the deadline for the payment
>   of an invoice. In BtoB, the maturity date indicates when the customer
>   wants to pay us, defined during the contract it is usually a later date between 1 and 3 months
>   after the publishing of the bill. It's a calculated data, and
>   implemented in my application with the following code.

I have this code in my Invoice module I extracted it for you can tests :

```
<?php
class Config
{
    protected $amountDelayedDays;
    protected $paymentDay;
    protected $paymentCondition;

    public function getAmountDelayedDays()
    {
        return $this->amountDelayedDays;
    }

    public function getPaymentCondition()
    {
        return $this->paymentCondition;
    }

    public function getPaymentDay()
    {
        return $this->paymentDay;
    }


    public function setAmountDelayedDays($days)
    {
        $this->amountDelayedDays = $days;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setPaymentDay($days)
    {
        $this->paymentDay = $days;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setPaymentCondition($condition)
    {
        $this->paymentCondition = $days;
        return $this;
    }

}

class Test {
    /**
     * @param DateTime $dateInvoice
     * @param Config $config
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function calcMaturityDate(\DateTime $dateInvoice, $config)
    {
        if ($config->getPaymentCondition() == 'delayed') {
            $dateMaturity = clone $dateInvoice;
            $startDay = $dateMaturity->format('j');

            $dateMaturity->modify("+{$config->getAmountDelayedDays()} days");
            $endDay = $dateMaturity->format('j');

            if ($startDay != $endDay && $endDay < 30) {
                $dateMaturity->modify('last day of last month');
            } else {
                $dateMaturity->modify('last day of this month');
            }
            if ($config->getPaymentDay() != 0) {
                $dateMaturity->modify('+' . $config->getPaymentDay() . 'days');
            }
            return $dateMaturity;
        } else {
            return $dateInvoice;
        }
    }
}

$config = new Config;
$config->setPaymentDay(15);
$config->setAmountDelayedDays(60);
$config->setPaymentCondition('delayed');

$test = new Test;
$date = $test->calcMaturityDate(new DateTime('2015-01-31'), $config);

var_dump($date);

?>
```

I have to calculate a maturity date from the date of invoice.

If my invoice is dated at **2014-11-30** and my client is configured to be charged 2 month later & on the 15'(=60days + 15 ), I have to produce a maturity date like this :

> '2015-02-15'

For doing this I have to variables in my Config class :

`$config->getAmountDelayedDays()` and `$config->getPaymentDay()`

My code is not perfect to handle all problems. February changing years, custom value of days... Jumped month...

I think the problem is in

```
if ($startDay != $endDay && $endDay < 30) {
                $dateMaturity->modify('last day of last month');
            } else {
                $dateMaturity->modify('last day of this month');
            }
```

It's too simple to handle all cases, maybe it's wrong. I can't make my mind clear about this...

**Tests case**

I have units test testing this function I'm not passing

```
/**
     * Tests MaturityDate
     * 
     */
    public function testCanGiveCorrectMaturityDate()
    {
        $config = $this->parser->setConfig();
        $config->setAmountDelayedDays(60);
        $config->setPaymentDay(15);
        $config->setPaymentCondition('delayed');

        // From February Ok ?
        $dateInvoice = new \Datetime('2015-02-28');
        $maturityDate = $this->mock->calcMaturityDate($dateInvoice , $config);
        $this->assertEquals('15-05-2015', $maturityDate->format('d-m-Y'));

        // From February ok ?
        $dateInvoice = new \Datetime('2015-02-28');
        $config->setAmountDelayedDays(30);
        $config->setPaymentDay(0);
        $maturityDate = $this->mock->calcMaturityDate($dateInvoice , $config);
        $this->assertEquals('31-03-2015', $maturityDate->format('d-m-Y'));

        // New years and pass february
        $config->setAmountDelayedDays(90);
        $config->setPaymentDay(15);
        $dateInvoice = new \Datetime('2014-11-30');
        $maturityDate = $this->mock->calcMaturityDate($dateInvoice , $config);
        $this->assertEquals('15-03-2015', $maturityDate->format('d-m-Y'));

        // No delayed
        $config->setPaymentCondition('standard');
        $dateInvoice = new \Datetime('2014-11-30');
        $maturityDate = $this->mock->calcMaturityDate($dateInvoice , $config);
        $this->assertEquals('30-11-2014', $maturityDate->format('d-m-Y'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, you expect the paymentDay to be always 15th day of month of maturity, or next month, when date of maturity is later than 15th.

With this assumption your class would be:

```
public function calcMaturityDate(\DateTime $dateInvoice, $config)
{
        $dateMaturity = clone $dateInvoice;
        $dateMaturity->add(new \DateInterval("P{$config->getAmountDelayedDays()}D"));

        $payDay = $config->getPaymentDay();

        // patch 0 payDay to last day of month
        if (0 == $payDay) {
            $payDay = $dateMaturity->format('t');
        }

        if ($dateMaturity->format('j') > $payDay) {                
            $dateMaturity->modify('next month');                
        }
        $dateMaturity->setDate(
            $dateMaturity->format('Y'), 
            $dateMaturity->format('m'), 
            $payDay
        );

        return $dateMaturity;
}
```

Few notes:

- the class name is a bit misleading, as it returns payment date, not maturity date;
- maturity interval is 60 days, not 2 months;

For the last point I would recommend to refactor your config class to return `\DateInterval` for maturity interval instead of integer, so you will have flexibility to define 2 month interval as `"P2M"` or 60 days as `"P60D"` depending on business requirements:
If instead of

```
public function getAmountDelayedDays()
{
    return $this->amountDelayedDays;
}
```

you have

```
/**
* @return \DateInterval
*/ 
public function getDelayInterval()
{
    return $this->delayInterval;
}
```

the ugly line from above

```
$dateMaturity->add(new \DateInterval("P{$config->getAmountDelayedDays()}D"));
```

turns to elegant

```
$dateMaturity->add($config->getDelayInterval());
```

Comment: Hum, I didn't tried with DateInterval, but i don't think your code do the trick. Especially because I have multiple possibilities for paymentDate, end of month, on the 10th, on the 15th, on the 20th... it's completely random depends on client configurations. Plus i can't refactor my paymentDate method because it's an input given by an operator, in days, if he gives 127 days, how can I simply add 4M 7 days ?

Comment: I upvote your answer anyway because your approach is clearly good.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear about refactoring part. Just updated the answer to make it clear that no refactorin required for paymentDate. It is still integer day of month. Thanks for upvoting tho.

Comment: Just saw your changed tests. What `$config->setPaymentDay(0);` means? there are no 0th day in a month. Not in Gregorian calendar anyway.

Comment: Yes, 0 means this is the end of the month wich is taken. Means the client is charged a the end of the month after delay expired.

Comment: Ok, Hooli, I updated the code to handle this case. Somehow I missed it in the original description.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases a always convert the "friendly date" to a timestamp; do the math; then convert back to a friendly date.
Something like this:

```
$invoice_date = "2014-11-30";
$ts_invoice_date = time($invoice_date);
$ts_maturity_month = $ts_invoice_date + (60*24*60*60); //60 days*24hrs*60mins*60secs
$maturity_date = date("Y-m-15 00:00:00", $ts_maturity_month);
```

Comment: I just realized that if $ts_maturity_month works out to something more than the 15th of the month you'll need to add another month.  So just add another 20 days or so and calculate $ts_maturity_month again: 80*24*60*60;

Comment: It's not always the 15th day of the month this data is coming from a variable too. Works on timestamp is exactly what do the Datetime object. I prefer not to use procedural methods.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: [Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [Time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

> date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week'))

[strtotime documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Your question:

> I have to calculate a maturity date from the date of invoice.

You can use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+60 days'))` and that will handle odd/even number of days in month, as well as fix to hours (if you need that precision)..

A date `2014-11-30` with `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ $amountDelayedDays days'))` yelds the correct date.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but you don't answer at any of my problems here.

Comment: I am not a native english speaker, so try to understand this answer, I will edit with a better explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I prefer and OOP approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think i get what your trying to do and I have had to do something similar. You basically want something to determine if the current day of the month is less than 15 and if it is it remains the 15th of this month else if its say the 20th of the same month then date is 15th of next month?. I think this is how I am reading this. If this is the case then you need to compare the day of the invoice to the 15th and if less than its the same month or if its greater than then its the next month. It then gets interesting as are you allowing a leverage period of say 5 days before the due date. A factor on what I was working on I used. This could be the case if the date of the invoice was the 14th and you set payment date on the 15th. With the logic the client would only have a day to pay the invoice. I think we went with the 15th minus 5 days.

Comment: Not exactly, I edited my post to explain what is a Maturity date, and my code is, incomplete but almost works. You should take a lot at it to understand.